# iOS Base SDK to Support iOS 7

Tags: ios, app-store, ios7

I have just submitted my iOS 7 compatible app using the Xcode 5 GM and iOS 7 SDK GM.  My base SDK is set at iOS 7 GM and my Deployment Target is set at 6.0, I am wanting my app to support iOS versions 6.0 and up.  I know that those settings are correct, however I am wondering if there is anything extra I need to do so that when the app goes live it says "Optimized for iOS 7" or whatever phrasing Apple is going to use for this.  Just like they did with the iPhone 5 "This app is optimized for the iPhone 5".  Anybody have an idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing else you have to, or can, do. I don't know if the App Store will display something like "Optimized for iOS 7". If it does show that once iOS 7 is released to the general public, then having built against the 7.0 SDK will probably be how Apple determines whether it's optimized or not.

Answer (score 1):

App icons:
- For iPhone, iOS 7 app icons have grown to 120×120 pixels, compared to 114×114 pixels in iOS 6. 
- For iPad, iOS 7 app icons should measure in at 152×152 pixels, instead of the 144×144 pixels in iOS 6.

Notes: IOS 7 & 6 UI are different. You still need to support iOS 6.

[All details are in iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174)

Things Every App Should Do

Make sure that app content is discernible through translucent UI elements—such as bars and keyboards—and the transparent status bar. In iOS 7, view controllers use full-screen layout (to learn more, see Using View Controllers).

Redesign custom bar button icons. In iOS 7, bar button icons are lighter in weight and have a different style. For some design guidance, see “Bar Button Icons”.

Prepare for borderless buttons by reassessing the utility of button background images and bezels in your layout.

Examine your app for hard-coded UI values—such as sizes and positions—and replace them with those you derive dynamically from system-provided values. Use Auto Layout to help your app respond when layout changes are required. (If you’re new to Auto Layout, learn about it by reading Auto Layout Guide.)

Examine your app for places where the metrics and style changes of UIKit controls and views affect the layout and appearance. For example, switches are wider, grouped tables are no longer inset, and progress views are thinner. For more information on specific UI elements, see Bars and Bar Buttons, Content Views, Controls, and Temporary Views.
Adopt Dynamic Type. In iOS 7, users can adjust the text size they see in apps. When you adopt Dynamic Type, you get text that responds appropriately to user-specified size changes. For more information, see Using Fonts.

Expect users to swipe up from the bottom of the screen to reveal Control Center. If iOS determines that a touch that begins at the bottom of the screen should reveal Control Center, it doesn’t deliver the gesture to the currently running app. If iOS determines that the touch should not reveal Control Center, the touch may be slightly delayed before it reaches the app.

Revisit the use of drop shadows, gradients, and bezels. Because the iOS 7 aesthetic is smooth and layered—with much less emphasis on using visual effects to make UI elements look physical—you may want to rethink these effects.

If necessary, update your app to best practices for iOS 6—such as Auto Layout and storyboards—and ensure that the app doesn’t use deprecated APIs.